# Is there a global JavaScript event when a URL in browser is clicked or a page is posted back Vs click event of each URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, dom-events

I need to capture some important information whenever a user either clicks on a URL i.e. get request for a URL, as well as when a post back happens in ASP.Net pages.

**Question**: Is there a single global event handler in JavaScript that can be used in this situation?

I could write a click/submit event handler for every possible URL click or a page post back, but it would be best if I could use a single global event handler for all URL clicks and all form submits. I would put this global handler in the master page of my ASP.Net application.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to to use  following code to handle all POST submits from an ASP.Net page, but it doesn't fire. In ASP.Net page, there is only one form per page, so I attach an event handler to the first form in the document in code snippet below.

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () { alert('form submitted'); }
```

**UPDATE 2**

In ASP.Net aspx pages, the form submit event does not fire if the above code snippet is used.  In rendered html of an ASP.Net aspx page, the following `form` tag is emitted. As one can see the onsubmit is tied some ASP.Net specific logic, but not sure what is preventing the above event handler from firing.

```
  <form method="post" action="./Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fnewcom%2fProducts%2fBrowseProducts.aspx%3fsw%3d1099&amp;sw=1099"
   onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" 
   onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 
   'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_btnVAMLogin')" id="aspnetForm"
   onreset="if (window.setTimeout) window.setTimeout(&#39;DES_OnReset(false);&#39;, 100);">
```

**UPDATE 3**

1. Based on the answer by Jdsfighter, all the URLs  in aspx page can be attached to the same click handler.
2. For attaching a global form submit handler, one of the following 2 approaches worked for me. In code snippets below, the common JavaScript that is being called on form submit event is `setStartTime()`. **These are the only 2 approaches that I found worked for creating a global form submit event handler in aspx Webforms pages.**

*Add the global JavaScript using code-behind of master page or content page*

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.Page, this.GetType(), "start", "setStartTime();");
```

*Add onsubmit attribute to form markup in master page or content page*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="min-height: 100%; margin: 0" onsubmit="setStartTime();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event listener on the tag name.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a page postback? I am thinking a form submit handler should suffice.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to locally store some data whenever user submits from an ASP.Net page either through URL click or a postback of ASP.Net page. Your answer takes care of the first part of the problem. But many times a user submits a page in other ways like clicking a button etc.

Comment: You should be able to do that on the submit handler I would think. Just do whatever operations you need to.

Comment: I tried this JavaScript, but it doesn't fire at all:  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () { alert('form submitted'); }  . It should fire whenever a form is submitted i.e. a POST request is sent from an ASP.Net page, but nothing happens.

Comment: What about doing exactly the same as I did in my example above, except use `form` as your tag name, and `onsubmit` as the argument instead of `onclick`

Comment: Not all A elements are links, and AREA elements are also links. There is a [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links) collection that is all the links in a page, it includes A and AREA elements, but not A elements with no href attribute (anchors).

Comment: @Jdsfighter, I tried your suggestion, but still onsubmit did not fire.    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
        for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
            elements[i].onsubmit = function () {
                alert('1111');
            }
        }

Comment: That's rather strange. Look at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQmqxd).

Comment: @Jdsfighter, You are right that it fires in a regular web page, but ASP.Net does something with submit event that causes it to not fire as expected. I don't know why exactly. I have tried your suggestion  in an ASP.Net aspx page.

Comment: @Jdsfighter, Look at `UPDATE 2` under my post to see how the form tag gets rendered in an ASP.Net aspx page. There may be something in the rendered form tag that prevents our custom form onsubmit to fire.

Comment: @Jdsfighter, May be for security reasons ASP.Net  framework does not allow changing the form's onsubmit handler using client-side code.

Comment: @Sunil, I've looked into it a bit and found [this forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1069601.aspx?I+want+to+use+onsubmit+asp+net+wont+let+me+) on the issue. Perhaps it will be of some use for you.

Comment: @Jdsfighter, Thanks for that forum post. It helped.

Comment: @Jdsfighter, It will be good to mention in your answer either the forum post you pointed me to or just some small explanation for a global form submit handler. I have added specific details under UPDATE 3.